# Type hinting v duck typing

Tags: oop, design-patterns, interface, duck-typing

Using the following simple Example (coded in php):

```
public function doSomething(Registry $registry)
{
    $object = $registry->getData('object_key');
    if ($object) {
        //use the object to do something
    }
}

public function doSomething($registry)
{
    $object = $registry->getData('object_key');
    if ($object) {
        //use the object to do something
    }
}
```

What are the benefits of either approach?

Both will ultimately fail just at different points:

The first example will fail if an object not of type Registry is passed, and the second will fail if the object passed does not implement a getData method.

How do you choose when to use either approach?

Answer (score 0):

Those are 2 different design approaches. The responsibility falls on the developer(s) to make sure either methods won't fail.

Type hinting is a more robust approach while duck typing gives you more flexibility.